# How to communicate between Vue instances

Tags: vue.js

If I define a component like:

```
Vue.component("hello", {
    name: "hello",
    data: ()=>{ return {color:"black"}  },
    template: "<div><div :style='{color:color}'>TEST</div><button @click='turnred'>TURN RED</button></div>",
    methods:{
        turnred(){ this.$emit("turnred","red") }
    },
    created(){
        this.$on("turnred", function(c){this.color = c;})
    }
})
```

And if I make 2 instances like:

```
<div id="a1">
    <hello />
</div>
<div id="a2">
    <hello />
</div>


new Vue({
    el: "#a1",
    data:{}
})
new Vue({
    el: "#a2",
    data:{}
})
```

I wonder how can I make both hello instances text color red?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a bus that is shared between the two instances. You can create a bus by creating a new Vue instance in the prototype chain.

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();

Vue.component("hello", {
    name: "hello",
    data: ()=>{ return {color:"black"}  },
    template: "<div><div :style='{color:color}'>TEST</div><button @click='turnred'>TURN RED</button></div>",
    methods:{
        turnred(){ this.$bus.$emit("turnred","red") },
        changeColor(color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.$bus.$on("turnred", this.changeColor)
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        this.$bus.$off("turnred", this.changeColor);
    }
})
new Vue({
    el: "#a1",
    data:{}
})
new Vue({
    el: "#a2",
    data:{}
})
```